# Access objects that haven't been created via Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I'm using Blend for the first time, for a WPF C# project.  I have an expander object that I'm creating on a button press, like below.

```
var name = selectedItem.Name;
var expander = new Expander {Header = name};
```

As you can see, I set the expander header by grabbing it from the selected item that creates the actual expander.

My question is that when I open this project in blend, I can't see the expander because it's not created yet.  How do I set a default background color for each new expander created?

I'd also be glad to do it via the code itself instead of blend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in code, instead of in blend, you would do something like this.

```
var name = selectedItem.Name;
var expander = new Expander {Header = name};

var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
var brush = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#00ff1e");
expander.Background = brush;
```

I'm sure there are easier ways, but this works.